# How can I write a query in SQL Server to capture prior month data?

Tags: sql-server, date

My problem statement is trying to capture the data for the prior month, using the max(date) for the data set. For example if my MAX(DISCHARGE DATE) = APRIL, 12, 2020.

I would like my query to capture data from MARCH 1, 2020 to MARCH 31, 2020.

```
select [ENC_KEY_MAIN], MAX([Discharge Date]) AS LastActivity 
from vw_HOME_CLINTIGRITY 
group by [ENC_KEY_MAIN] 
having MAX([Discharge Date]) < DATEADD(MM, -3, MAX([Discharge Date]));
```

Comment: Provide sample data and your attempt please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `EOMONTH()` and `DATEADD()` as

```
DECLARE @MXD DATE = (SELECT EOMONTH(MAX(Col), -1) FROM Table);

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Col <= @MXD
      AND 
      Col >= DATEADD(Day, -(DAY(@MXD)-1), @MXD);
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a94fa0329ed8143777395816f459462a)

Comment: I guess the column is a `DATE` not a `DATETIME`

Comment: @AaronBertrand _"I would like my query to capture data from MARCH 1, 2020 to MARCH 31, 2020."_ So the OP want to filter the data

Comment: the max(discharge date) keeps changing according to the dataset uploaded. Would it be better to just tag a row with a month-yyyy and then just select the month prior to the max(month) ? @AaronBertrand

Comment: the max(discharge date) keeps changing according to the dataset uploaded. Would it be better to just tag a row with a month-yyyy and then just select the month prior to the max(month) ? @Sami

Answer (score -1):

declare @dt int = select month(max([Discharge Date]))-1 from vw_HOME_CLINTIGRITY

select [ENC_KEY_MAIN], DATENAME(MONTH,getdate()-29) AS LastActivity 
from vw_HOME_CLINTIGRITY

where month([Discharge Date])=@dt